# Calling COM components from a dll file (wirtten in VB) from C

Tags: c, vb.net

I have dll which is coded in `VB` and I wanted to call its `COM components` from plain `C`. Below are the few lines of codes of that `dll`. Suppose I want to call the method `Initialize()` from plain `C`, what should be the arguments of the method `CoCreateInstance` in `C`.

I am successful in calling all the methods of this `dll` from `C++` but I want to call in from `C`. Could you please help me regarding this.

```
Namespace Thermodynamics

<System.Serializable()> <ComClass(Calculator.ClassId, Calculator.InterfaceId, Calculator.EventsId)>
Public Class Calculator

    Public Const ClassId As String = "5F2B671E-FA61-401e-8D14-71FB5B328F9B"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "0EA44EDE-AD65-435c-B8CC-0D1146BD182B"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "0817BD3F-5278-4e49-A7FB-92416A8A7E4E"

    Private _availablecomps As Dictionary(Of String, ConstantProperties)

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes the calculator and loads the compound databases into memory.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispId(1)> Sub Initialize()

        'load databases
        _availablecomps = New Dictionary(Of String, ConstantProperties)

        'ChemSep
        Me.LoadCSDB()

        'load DWSIM XML database
        Me.LoadDWSIMDB()

    End Sub
```

Comment: How did you do it in C++?

Comment: First I registered the dll by using regasm. This process generated a .tlb file which can be used directly in C++. Following is the Code for calling it from C++.

Comment: #import "C:/DTLSource/DTLSource/DTL master/DWSIM/bin/Debug/DTL.tlb" raw_interfaces_only

Comment: Does your version of c support COM objects? If it does not, then you cannot consume the above code written as a COM object. If your c compiler supports COM then you can use CreateObject() assuming the object been registered as per regasm. So .net cannot create win32 .dll''s that can be called from c, c++ etc (non managed code). So .net dll's are NOT native win32 .dll's that can be linked to + called as routines from c. So .net cannot create non managed .dl''s for consumption via non managed code except when COM objects are supported.

Answer (score -1):

This is the complete C++ code for call the Initialize() method.

```
#include "tchar.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include <comutil.h>
#include <string>
#include <xstring>


#import "C:/DTLSource/DTLSource/DTL-master/DWSIM/bin/Debug/DTL.tlb"  raw_interfaces_only
using namespace DTL;


int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     // Initialize COM.
 HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    _CalculatorPtr ptrinterface(_uuidof(Calculator));
 ptrinterface->Initialize();

    CoUninitialize();
return 0;
}
```